# Form: "Select all" button with multiple-choice checkboxes

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make the "Select all" and "Remove all" buttons  work in my form but i'm having lots of trouble. In fact, if I remove the "[]" (array) to the name attribute of the checkboxes, that javascript code totally works. But I need these checkboxes to be multiple-choice so that code isn't working.

I leave here the HTML and JS code related to the checkboxes, but I recommend you to check this JS Fiddle, so you can check it more graphically:

https://jsfiddle.net/28dsnmxs/

**HTML Code:**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="h[]" value="1" id="g"> SMS
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="h[]" value="2" id="g"> E-mail
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="h[]" value="3" id="g"> Phone
<br/>
<input type="button" id="prueba" name="sub" value="Check all"     onclick="checkall(document.formulario.h)">
<input type="button" name="sub" value="Uncheck all"  onclick="uncheckall(document.formulario.h)">
```

**JS Code:**

```
function checkall(chk) {

    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < chk.length; i++) {
        chk[i].checked = true;
    }

}
function uncheckall(chk) {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < chk.length; i++) {
        chk[i].checked = false;
    }
}
```

How can I make it work? Ideas avoiding jQuery are preferred, but no problem if there is no other way. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To access key of object which is not a valid `JavaScript Identifier`, use [**`bracket-notation`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation)

Use `document.formulario['h[]']` to select all `name = "h[]"` elements

```js
function checkall(chk) {
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < chk.length; i++) {
    chk[i].checked = true;
  }

}

function uncheckall(chk) {
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < chk.length; i++) {
    chk[i].checked = false;
  }
}
```

```html
<form method="POST" action="" name="formulario" id="form">
  <input type="checkbox" name="h[]" value="1" id="g">SMS
  <br/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="h[]" value="2" id="g">E-mail
  <br/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="h[]" value="3" id="g">Phone
  <br/>
  <input type="button" id="prueba" name="sub" value="Check all" onclick="checkall(document.formulario['h[]'])">
  <input type="button" name="sub" value="Uncheck all" onclick="uncheckall(document.formulario['h[]'])">
</form>
```